# How can I determine if an Outlook MailItem is an unsaved draft?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, office-interop, mailitem

As far as I can find there is no property on a `MailItem` one can access to discover if a `MailItem` is a draft.

One could check `MailItem.Categories` and see if it includes `Drafts` but this seems insufficient because:

Drafts don't have to be stored in the `Drafts` folder, they can be dragged and dropped into other folders.

The fact that a draft email retains its draftyness even if moved out of the Drafts folder indicates there must be some other way in which a `MailItem` is marked as a draft, but I haven't been able to find it.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

New items don't have the `EntryID` property set. The value is assigned by the *store provider* when an item is saved to the store.

If the item is already saved to the store you can use the `PR_MESSAGE_FLAGS` property value which contains a bitmask of flags that indicate the origin and current state of a message.

> This property is initialized by the client or message store provider when a message is created and saved for the first time and then updated periodically by the message store provider, a transport provider, and the MAPI spooler as the message is processed and its state changes.

Try to check for the MSGFLAG_UNSENT value which stands for the following:

> The message is still being composed. It is saved, but has not been sent. The client or provider has read/write access to this flag until the first IMAPIProp::SaveChanges call and read-only thereafter. If a client doesn't set this flag by the time the message is sent, the message store provider sets it when IMessage::SubmitMessage is called. Typically, this flag is cleared after the message is sent.

See [PidTagMessageFlags Canonical Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagmessageflags-canonical-property) for more information about possible values.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `MailItem.Sent` property - it will be false for the draft (editable)  messages.

Comment: I was under the impression that MailItems included all emails and thus that this flag might be misleading for emails received?

Comment: `MailItem` object represents both sent and unsent messages. `Sent` property distinguishes between the two types - it will be true for both sent and received messages. And false for the unsent drafts messages. `MSGFLAG_UNSENT` bit in the `PR_MESSAGE_FLAGS` MAPI property is the only difference. Take a look at a message in MFCMAPI or OutlookSpy (click IMessage button).